# Understanding nested array c++ in image scanning context

Tags: c++, image

I came across this sample code on openCV library. What does the line p[j] = table[p[j]] do? I have come across multi dimensional arrays but not something like this before.

```
Mat& ScanImageAndReduceC(Mat& I, const uchar* const table)
{
    // accept only char type matrices
    CV_Assert(I.depth() == CV_8U);
    int channels = I.channels();
    int nRows = I.rows;
    int nCols = I.cols * channels;
    if (I.isContinuous())
    {
        nCols *= nRows;
        nRows = 1;
    }
    int i,j;
    uchar* p;
    for( i = 0; i < nRows; ++i)
    {
        p = I.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for ( j = 0; j < nCols; ++j)
        {
            p[j] = table[p[j]];
        }
    }
    return I;
}
```

Comment: It depends what `I.ptr<uchar>(i)` is doing. Maybe this is using it as a look-up index value in `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing color replacement by using a table where each pixel intensity maps to some other value.  Commonly used for techniques like color grading, histogram adjustment, or even thresholding.

Here, the table contains unsigned char values and is being indexed by the value of the pixel.  The pixel's intensity `p[i]` is used as an index into the table, and the value at that index is then written to that pixel, replacing its original value.

Answer (score 1):

It is a lookup table conversion.

The pixels of image(I) would be converted by means of table.
For example, the pixel with value 100 would be changed to 10 if table[100]=10.

Your sample code is introduced in OpenCV tutorial which is well explained of what the code does.

https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html